# Preload Onmouseover Image

Tags: image, hover

Im working with the following line:

```
<a <img src="images/m1.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='images/m0.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='images/m1.png'"/></a>
```

So, I simply change one image to another on hover. The problem is that after hover it takes another second to load the second image. It looks slow and ugly...

My question is: Is it possible to make browser to load the second before the user actually interacts with the first image?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use Javascript to define your image somewhere in the header

```
img[i] = new Image();
img[i].src = <URL>;
```